# Siri knows all my contacts but contacts app doesnt?

Tags: iphone, contacts, siri

I have contacts on my phone that I can ask Siri to call, and it works fine.
I can say "call John Smith" or "show John Smith" and that contact shows up.

On the other hand, if I go to the Contacts app and search for "John Smith" the app won't show it.

What could be happening here? I have two iPhones, an iPhone 5S and an iPhone 7, both are on Sprint's network, and the issue is occurring on both iPhones.

Comment: Trying to rule out the obvious: When you go to Contacts and select "Groups" have you selected "All iCloud"? Also, is the iCloud contacts list any different from the contacts list on your iPhones? E.g. it could be that John Smith is on the iCloud contacts list, but not on the phone.